# Beginner Java JADE - Class not found error (on Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, agents-jade

SOLVED: When creating an agent via the GUI, you need to include the package name when identifying which class name in the agent details. a screenshot is attached. I hope this helps any other beginners to JADE that meet similar problems.

[JADE GUI Screenshot with the solution to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m05U.png)

I am currently working on a project where JADE will be utilised.

I have added the jar file to my project and I am using a run configuration to display the GUI and run my code. This is the code for the only class in the project:

```
import jade.core.Agent;

public class JadeProj extends Agent {

    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        System.out.println("Agent is Created");
    }
    @Override
    protected void takeDown() {
        System.out.println("Agent is Destroyed");
    }
}
```

the run configuration has jade.Boot as its main class and the program argument is just -gui. A very simple program that I had working but now seems it doesn't want to... I was using youtube videos to help me get the basics so this implementation of JADE was taken from there.

when I am trying to create a new agent on the GUI, I get this message:

```
 ((action 
 (agent-identifier 
   :name ams@192.168.0.26:1099/JADE 
   :addresses (sequence http://DESKTOP-OMFCBSV:7778/acc)) 
 (create-agent 
   :agent-name agent1 
   :class-name JadeProj 
   :container 
     (container-ID 
       :name Main-Container 
       :protocol JADE-IMTP 
       :address "<Unknown Host>" 
       :protocol JADE-IMTP))) 

 (internal-error " - Caused by:  Class JadeProj for agent ( agent-identifier :name agent1@192.168.0.26:1099/JADE ) not found - Caused by:  JadeProj"))
```

I have the developing Multi-Agents with JADE book by the JADE developers but I haven't found anything so far that can help me. It mentions changing classpath in DOS command prompt but would that affect all my other projects classpaths? I did try it but it didn't make much of a difference.

also as a side question, I plan to use it in conjunction with the Paho MQTT library and to use the paho library I would need to add it as a dependency through maven. what I wanted to know is if adding it as an external JAR instead of adding it as a dependency would make much of a difference.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified class name

```
-gui testAgent:jade.core.Agent.JadeProj
```

Comment: is this suppose to go within the program arguments? it didnt work when i placed it there. it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

For the side question, what maven basically does is to download the inserted dependencies, making easier to whole jar file management procedure.

When you bundle your project into a jar, if you choose to include all the corresponding jars-libraries, maven includes all of them them. It doesn't matter if they come from a maven repo or are inserted manually.

hope it helps